# False or true statement about sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For any $\varepsilon>0$ $\exists N$ such that $n\geqslant N$ implies that $p_n<\dfrac{1}{\varepsilon}$. Can we conclude that $p_n\to 0$?

Above statement is very similar to definition of sequence that converges to zero.

But I think that it's false. Taking $p_n=1$ which does not converges to zero.

But for any $\varepsilon\in (0,1)$ $\exists N$ such that $n\geqslant N$ implies that $p_n=1<\dfrac{1}{\varepsilon}$.

Am I true?

Comment: Take $p_n=-1$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example doesn't work, you can choose $\epsilon = 2$. However, the statement remains false as the sequence $x_n = -n$ shows.

If you additionally demand $x_n$ to be nonnegative, the claim is true.

Comment: How to prove it in the case $x_n\geqslant 0$?

Comment: You pretty much just need to apply the definition of convergence.

Comment: By contradiction. Let $p_n$ does not converges to zero. Then exists $\varepsilon_0>0$ such that $\forall N$ $\exists n\geqslant N$ that implies $p_n\geqslant \varepsilon_0$. But by condition for $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{\varepsilon_0}$ $\exists N_0$ such that $n\geqslant N_0$ implies that $p_n<\varepsilon_0$. And we get contradiction. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, even though it's not necessary to work with a contradiction.

Comment: Really? I couldn't without contradiction. Can you demonstrate?

Comment: Let $\delta > 0$ be arbitrary. Choose an $N$ large enough so that $0 \le p_n \le \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ for all $n > N$, where $\epsilon = \frac{1}{\delta}$. This means $0 \le p_n \le \delta$ for all $n > N$, therefore the sequence converges to zero.

Comment: How you get $0\leqslant p_n\leqslant 1/{\varepsilon}$? For this you must choose $\varepsilon>0$. I can't understand...

Comment: I simply choose $\epsilon = \frac{1}{\delta} > 0$.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your counterexample only works for $\let\epsilon\varepsilon\epsilon\in(0,1)$, but it should work for any $\epsilon>0$. As it doesn't work for $\epsilon = 2$, say, your counterexample is not a counterexample.

Consider $p_n=-1$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

Above statement is not true as for example consider any strictly decreasing sequence of negative reals.